# wso2 using clone and aggregate with datamapper

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

So I am using Clone Mediator and Aggregate Mediator to get the two(2) response from the API in a single request. But the problem is that the first request returns an error from DataMapper Mediator (http://pastebin.com/7P43ZbAa) and the second request returned my expected response (http://pastebin.com/2WbCvi9z) without any errors.

Here's my api config
http://pastebin.com/2ytGEkFk

Comment: Can you share your mapping configurations as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is the configuration for mapping. http://pastebin.com/FVmgwDwd

Comment: Is it possible to share the entire CAPP?

Comment: Here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B05yApyNp_cpaUFaWkZyZi1KMHM

Comment: I don't see any error when I invoke the API. Can you tell me the steps to get the error?

Comment: I got the error from the first invoke and then the second invoke will work just fine and it just repeats like that.